# Printing part of web page not working with css changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I want to print part of the page and using following method to do it. It prints that part of page but not with CSS effect

```
<body>
  <h1><b><center>This is a test page for printing</center></b><hr color=#00cc00 width=95%></h1>
  <b>Div 1:</b> <a href="javascript:printDiv('printthis')">Print</a><br>
  <div id="printthis" class="printthis">
    <div id="div1" class="div1">This is the div1's print output</div>
    <div id="divx2" class="div2">This is the div2's print output</div>
    <div id="divx3" class="div3">This is the div3's print output</div>
  </div>


  <br><br>
  <b>Div 2:</b> <a href="javascript:printDiv('div2')">Print</a><br>
  <div id="div2">This is the div2's print output</div>
  <br><br>
  <b>Div 3:</b> <a href="javascript:printDiv('div3')">Print</a><br>
  <div id="div3">This is the div3's print output</div>
  <iframe name="print_frame" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="about:blank"></iframe>
</body>
```

I changed the above example which i found on web so that it can use the print css.

For some reason it is not implementing the css when i print

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOGdXv

Current Printout doesn't reflect event font-size or other properties, it just show three lines.

```
This is the div1's print output
This is the div2's print output
This is the div3's print output
```

Comment: use `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into this:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/tips-and-tricks-for-print-style-sheets/#force-background-images-and-colors

You probably need this CSS:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        print-color-adjust: exact;
```

**EDIT:**

In your javascript your are not using the css you provided, but referring to an non-exisiting css file. I minified your styling and added it as the `printDivCSS` variable.

I updated your codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LObyqO

This works. I hope this helps you understand the issue.

Comment: what about the font-size even that doesnt work or reflect in print version

Comment: But  it is mentioned as print class will that not work

Comment: Your javascript code is not taking that styling to the printing frame, but referring to a css file, that does not exist in your codepen.

Comment: thanks you have a point i thought it will use the css defined in print media query.